# How to browse a font by characters from a given codepage?

Tags: fonts, unicode, character-encoding

Most of the font manager tools display characters of a font grouped by subsets of the *Unicode* character set. Is there a tool that displays the characters grouped by the particular *code page* that a given font supports? I.e. for the font `Arial`, display all characters that are part of the `Windows 1252` code page.

//edit:

The only program that does exactly this is Windows Character Map:

[image]

The problem with Character Map is that:

- I'm not sure how do entries in the menu map to actual code pages. For the `Windows*` ones, one could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28VS.85%29.aspx) table (i.e. `Windows: Central Europe` maps to `Windows-1250`), but what about the `DOS` ones
- certain code pages are missing in the menu
- inside of the properties of the font file, there is a list of code pages that a given font supports. Seeing *those* code pages would be helpful, if possible
- there is no way that I've found to see the character code from the code page selected, only the UTF-16 character code is shown (`U+XXXX`), though for this one could use the [conversion](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1250/grid.htm?hyperlink=Y) table.

Comment: The Character Map (CharMap) utility of Windows has such a feature. But do you mean a font editing tool?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the response; I've updated the question. The reason I've asked the question was to understand `roughly`, how AltCodes (and actually, fonts in general) work. There are at least three ways one can enter AltCodes to a given program (+/0/non0 prefixed) and each of those methods may possibly yield different results. I.e. the + prefix uses the UTF-16 character code of the character (I guess) while the 0 prefix uses the character code of the code page associated with the currently set Input Language. Thought that maybe by understanding fonts more I'll also grasp the AltC's.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jukka, what I ended up doing was to swap the font on the webpage that displayed the `code page` to `Unicode` mapping. Hopefully it doesn't matter if glyphs of the font are accessed through the Unicode code (UTF-8 on the webpage) or through the code page code. Here is the Stylish script to do just that:

```
@-moz-document regexp("http://www\.fileformat\.info/info/charset/.*/grid.htm.*") {

    body {
        font-family: 'Magneto', 'Unicode BMP Fallback SIL'  !important;
    }
}
```